# Weight painting doesn't change the VertexGroups

Tags: vertices, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I have a hand mesh and an armature with 24 bones. I have used automatic weighing but I didn't like the results so I used the weight paint to change the weights. Now, when I try to select the vertices in a vertex group, the selection only consists of old vertices Here are some screenshots.

Here is the weight I painted for vertex group 14.

[image]

Here is the vertex group selection. This area is the same as automatic weights for vertex group 14.

[image]

I have used the following code for selection:

```
bone = '14'
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action="DESELECT")
bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_set_active(group = bone)
bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_select()
```

I want the vertex selection to be same as the weight painting.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you were changing weights (e.g subtracting from previous weight paint) it doesn't mean they were removed from group. Vertex can have 0 weight yet still be in the group. Viewport menu > Weights > Clear or Vertex Weight Edit modifier with certain threshold settings can avoid that.